# "some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organization" Start Menu Settings

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Windows 10 does not let me add tiles to my start menu and I do not know why.

I had a school account on my laptop but I removed it and everything else was fixed but not my start menu settings.

Comment: So, are you now using a local account with admin privileges?

Comment: Yes i am using a local account with admin privileges @GabrielaGarcia

Answer (score 0):

Below are some fixes that might help in your case.
I suggest before starting to create at least a System Restore point,
so to have an easy way of undoing them, just in case.

**Allow full Microsoft telemetry**

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Data Collection*
- Double-click "Allow Telemetry" and set it to Enabled and
  the drop-down menu entry to "3 - Full"
- Click OK
- Reboot

Later on you could return this to "1 - Basic", if you wish.

**Check for corruption**

Check for Windows system errors using the following:

- Run `chkdsk`
- Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
  and the DISM command at the end of the article